# App does not work on real machine Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem that I still don't understand: I have an app successfully submitted to the AppStore.

However, when I download and install the application, some devices I cannot operate on the application (Scroll, Tapped, ...). Specifically, I checked on 2 real iphone devices (ip 11 promax) 1 device works normally, 1 device I can't: Scroll, Tapped, .... I also try on iphone 8plus also get same mistake.

I don't understand why the problem. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!

**Update**

[image]

and **Deployment target: 8.0**

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?  Is there any correlation between iOS versions and the broken versions of the app?  Without a lot more information there is very little we can do to help you.

Comment: Try: * Power phone OFF, then back on. * Delete the app and reinstall it. * Attach the failing device to your Mac, and test a Debug build.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I checked, it doesn't seem to work on ios version 14.8. Instead of having to update the ios version for the real device, can I configure it to reduce the version? Or anything else. As in the update above how I have configured for publishing.

Comment: What's the `version`  working? I think you can update the iOS version that's working.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I checked, it doesn't seem to work on ios version 14.8. Instead of having to update the ios version for the real device, can I configure it to reduce the version? Or anything else. As in the update above how I have configured for publishing?

Comment: Since there's no other logs on why it's not working on ios 14.8.I would suggest updating the ios version for the real device.